# Behind elements in Position: Absolute continer HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a two boxes that i used. What i need to do is the next  after the two boxes must not go under but to go after even in mobile view.

```css
.bg_info_profile {
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_red_left {
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_red_right {
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_info_profile">
  <div class="bg_profile_red_left">
    asdf
  </div>
  <div class="bg_profile_red_right">
    asdf
  </div>
</div>
```

**IMAGE:**
[image]

Comment: So you added nice demo, but decided not to add text the goes under? Demonstrate issue.

Comment: When I try to do that it only goes over the boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned elements are taken "out of the flow", which means they essentially provide no height to their parents, nor does their height and position affect siblings.

If you want these elements to instead affect the page in the way you expect, they can't be `position: absolute;` unless you want to specify a height on the container.

What you can do is instead just `float` them left and right, without using `position: absolute;` at all. The caveat is, `float` works very similar to `position: absolute;` in that the elements afterwards will ignore the height of floated elements.

Because of this, floated elements require a `clear: both;` after them, which essentially tells the rest of the elements to "account for the floated elements' heights". I've applied this `clear: both;` to a pseudo-element on the container, using `::after`.

```css
.bg_info_profile {
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.bg_info_profile::after {
   content: '';
   display: table;
   clear: both;
 }

.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_red_left {
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_red_right {
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_info_profile">
  <div class="bg_profile_red_left">
    asdf
  </div>
  <div class="bg_profile_red_right">
    asdf
  </div>
</div>

THIS IS SOME TEXT AFTER
```

Comment: @Philip Give me a second to fix this. This only *seems* like it works, but admittedly it does not. I was deceived because the padding on your container had the text positioned perfectly.

Comment: Oh I see well i just checked some of the text goes under the boxes. Thanks for telling by the way

Comment: I've modified my answer to be more complete and correct.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is

```
<div class="bg_info_profile">
      <div class="bg_profile_red_left">
        asdf
      </div>
      <div class="bg_profile_red_right">
      asdf
      </div>

    </div>
     <div class="clr"></div>
      <p>
      weewewewe
      </p>
```

And the css is

```
.bg_info_profile {
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  position:relative;
}

.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_red_left {
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
  width: 50%;
 float: left;

}

.bg_info_profile .bg_profile_red_right {
  background: yellow;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
  width: 50%;
 float: left;

}
.clr{
  clear:both;

}
```

And Fiddler link is https://jsfiddle.net/oys5v9uf/